# Django simple REST with class based view

Tags: django

I'm new to Django and I'm looking for a method to make class based views respond to GET,POST,PUT,DELETE with several methods in the class. e.g.

- index  #GET
- show   #GET
- new    #GET
- edit   #GET
- create #POST
- update #PUT
- delete #DELETE

My main reason is to organise my code in one class. Currently I'm using a class to handle the new and create actions and another to handle the edit and update actions. This feels a bit clunky.

I've used Spring, Symfony, Rails and they all provide an easy way to do this. There seems to be a lot of options with Django (tastypie, rest-framework) but I can't see any that support this exactly. Is there any way to support this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely positive, but I think you're mixing the REST term with "handling different types of requests in a single class". What rest-framework and Tastypie will enable is the resource definition, its serialization and deserialization, the plumbing to and from django models, the standardized API to your resources.

On the other hand, using just the [django class-based views](http://ccbv.co.uk/) you can get what you need: answer to different types of requests inside a single class formed of X, Y, Z mixins and point a single URL to it, but that doesn't make it exactly "REST".

Using a single CBV might seem like a good idea, but keep in mind that as views get more and more complex, the original clunkyness will certainly resurface in a more coupled way.

Edit: perhaps the [django-extra-views](https://github.com/AndrewIngram/django-extra-views) can help you in some way.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm just trying to find out what's possible and learn best practices. I was attempting to recreate what i've implemented with Spring. For example, i'll create 7 methods in a controller then expose them with annotations. Springs content negotiation will provide the correct serialisation. But even If i'm not using REST I still like to organise my code using this method. Now that I can see the range of out-of-the-box views Django offers (great link BTW) perhaps the approach I was taking is the correct one and then use Tastypie to expose my models where appropriate.